# problems installing vim-misc and vim-session plugins on mac / macvim

Tags: vim, macvim

When I follow github instructions for [vim-misc](https://github.com/xolox/vim-misc/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and [vim-sessions](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session/blob/master/INSTALL.md), after unzipping to `/Users/<me>/.vim/misc` and  `/Users/<me>/.vim/vim-session-master`, and then restarting macvim, I get

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc

E150: Not a directory: ~/.vim/doc
```

Also tried putting the two folders in `/Users/<me>/`  (where my .vimrc is) and in the two locations pointer by $VIM and $VIMRUNTIME from within macvim (`/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim`) all to no avail.

I guess I really don't understand how running the `:helptags <whatever>` starts up/completes installation of these plug-ins anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Before using using a plugin managers, plugins used to go directly into `~/.vim`, not into `~/.vim/pluginname`. That's when we ran `:helptags ~/.vim/doc`.

Then we had plugin manager, each with different specific way of doing things. Some even take care of registering the documentation of the plugins installed.

IMO, you'd better find a plugin manager suited to your need and use it. I remember a Q/A on vi.SE, you could start by reading it.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to install plugins manually instead of using one of plugin managers like `vim-plug` or others then you should add plugin directory to your `runtimepath`. Place this line to your .vimrc `set runtimepath+=/path/to/plugin`. I would not recommend to place plugins directly to `~/.vim` directory, use sub-folder instead (e.g. `/Users/<you>/.vim/plugins`).